# VLCJ player crashing in a JavaFX Scene

Tags: java, javafx, vlcj

I need multiple players on a JavaFX scene, with FXML, to do a CCTV monitoring system, displaying streams of live cameras.

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.factory.MediaPlayerFactory;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.EmbeddedMediaPlayer;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import static uk.co.caprica.vlcj.javafx.videosurface.ImageViewVideoSurfaceFactory.videoSurfaceForImageView;


public class allCamerasMainGridScreenController implements Initializable {
    public MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory;
    public  EmbeddedMediaPlayer embeddedMediaPlayer;

    @FXML BorderPane mainBorderPane;
    @FXML GridPane cameraViewGrid;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
            ImageView cameraView = new ImageView();
            mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
            embeddedMediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.mediaPlayers().newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
            cameraView.setPreserveRatio(true);
            cameraView.setFitHeight(340);
            embeddedMediaPlayer.videoSurface().set(videoSurfaceForImageView(cameraView));
            cameraViewGrid.add(cameraView,0,0);
            embeddedMediaPlayer.media().play("http://10.0.0.6:8081");
    }

}
```

With this code I can get a player running, but it crashes after a few seconds, throwing this message on IntelliJ

`Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`

Comment: This is a filesystem problem. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30837998/oracle-virtualbox-terminated-unexpectedly-with-exit-code-1073741819-0xc000000).

Comment: If it works (i.e. plays video) for a short while and then fatally crashes the JVM, this is more often than not because the Java object wrapping the native media player was unexpectedly garbage collected. That's *not* apparent from the code you posted however, but that's where I'd start looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the comments saying that the controller needs a hard reference, I think I was able to solve this properly.

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.factory.MediaPlayerFactory;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.EmbeddedMediaPlayer;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import static uk.co.caprica.vlcj.javafx.videosurface.ImageViewVideoSurfaceFactory.videoSurfaceForImageView;


public class mainGridScreenController implements Initializable {
    public MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory;
    public  EmbeddedMediaPlayer embeddedMediaPlayer;

    @FXML BorderPane mainBorderPane;
    @FXML GridPane cameraViewGrid;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        //Just by adding this two lines the controller isn't elegible for garbage collection anymore
        mainGridController mainGridController = new mainGridController();
        mainBorderPane.setUserData(this);


        ImageView cameraView = new ImageView();
        mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
        embeddedMediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.mediaPlayers().newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
        cameraView.setPreserveRatio(true);
        cameraView.setFitHeight(340);
        embeddedMediaPlayer.videoSurface().set(videoSurfaceForImageView(cameraView));
        cameraViewGrid.add(cameraView,0,0);
        embeddedMediaPlayer.media().play("http://10.0.0.6:8081");
    }

}
```

Comment: IMO setting those fields to static is not a good answer, and dodges the real issue. Instead, you need to understand why those objects were garbage collected by looking at the entire object graph - in your case this would mean looking at why the object that *contains* embeddedMediaPlayer is itself garbage collected, all the way up the object graph to your application class. Setting those fields to static might work if you only ever have one instance of this class, but just because it might work in this limited case doesn't make it the right solution.

Comment: I don't know if I got what the object that contains embeddedMediaPlayer is, you mean the ImageView? I really don't understand why it is being garbage collected if it hold a strong reference.

Comment: check the code that creates that controller class, what do you do with the object reference when you create that controller?